# Bootstrap AngularJS fullscreen table

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with a lot of columns and a horizontal scrollbar. I'm searshing a way to show it in fullscreen, like you can do in gmail when you want to see an mail attachement with a glyphicon-resize-full

If someone have an idea :)

edit : I'm trying with this :

```
<div id="overlayContainer" class="overlay">
<a href="#" class="closebtn glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small" ng-click="reduceElement()"></a>
<div id="overlayContent" class="overlay-content">
</div>
```

using a css to have a bigger table on a black background

```
<style>
.overlay {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .overlay a {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .overlay .closebtn {
        font-size: 40px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
    }
}
```

and I fill the div overlayContent or close it by this way :

```
$scope.fullScreenElement = function () {
            document.getElementById("overlayContainer").style.height = "100%";
            document.getElementById("overlayContainer").style.width = "100%";
            document.getElementById("overlayContent").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tableContent").innerHTML;
        };

        $scope.reduceElement = function () {
            document.getElementById("overlayContainer").style.height = "0%";
            document.getElementById("overlayContainer").style.width = "0%";
        };
```

But with that I can't use JS functions of my table :(

edit : Here is an example : http://plnkr.co/edit/1ge8r8zFANDNt2P2k0kI?p=preview
I couldn't reproduce it, but table should have horizontal scrollbar and you should't see lasts columns at the right. And if you expand it, you see the entire table but javascript like click on column name to sort (it's not in my Plunker) doesn't work

edit : I tried a second time with your           `angular.element(document.getElementById($scope.id)).addClass("overflowFullScreen");`
Nimmi, and it's better than my first try, it keeps JS functions. I continue with this, but looks good. Thank you !

final edit : I resolves lasts problems caused by z-index and a missing vertical scrollbar but it is done ! Thank you for your help !

Comment: Do you mean like a youtube like fullscreen, or the table taking up the whole page inside the browser?

Comment: I mean  the table taking up the whole page inside the browser.

Comment: You don't have a table in your HTML (and you're missing a `</div>`). And what does "I can't use JS functions of my table" mean?

Comment: Where is "tableContent" coming from?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this : http://plnkr.co/edit/X6VS4kBY7GmYl0mLMwma?p=preview

Comment: tableContent is a div id, wicch contains my table and some angular code inside, like ng-change="toggleCheckAll()" ng-model="checkAllCheckBox" or ng-click="downloadPdf()" in the div tableContent, just behind my table. Nimmi, thank you for your Plunker, but it's almost what I have, and what I want to do, is expand my table and have my js still ok in expanded table. I try to make a Planker too

Comment: Great so finally it looks like you are able to achieve your requirement.